# Remove foreign key in Hibernate DDL

Tags: java, hibernate

As we know Hibernate ddl is generating foreign key related to the JPA relation but Is there any way to make this foreign keys optionnal or disable it without adding any annotation in my JPA classes

this is the code used to generate the ddl :

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.addResource(mappingFile);  
cfg.setProperties(props);
SchemaExport scEx= new SchemaExport(cfg);
scEx.setDelimiter(";");
scEx.setOutputFile("mySCRIPT.sql");
scEx.setFormat(true);
scEx.execute(false, false, false, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to do it as far as I'm concerned (I've looked all over the hibernate internals).
You can do it if you really want, you need to change code in `org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl` that deals with the foreign keys:

```
final Iterator fkItr = table.getForeignKeyIterator();
```

But in order to do so you need to define some different implementations of some 'service' interfaces..
Also you will have to copy a lot of code from this class since there is no hook for the foreign keys.
(There is hook for a custom naming strategy, but this isn't what you want)

Anyway, if you just don't want to create those constraints, you can simple remove them from the generated script and manually execute it rather than letting hibernate run execute it